# Word order in Indirect Speech

Tags: grammar

The sentence "She didn't even know who Pirandello was" is in reported speech but my student asked why "was" goes at the end of the sentence.

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think that's "reported speech", which would be "She said she didn't know...".

Comment: I can't see any reported speech. Anyway, the answer is that it's because "who Pirandello was" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) and such clauses don't have subject-auxiliary inversion. The subject of the interrogative clause is "Pirandello", the verb is "was" and "who" is predicative complement.

Comment: Incidentally, you could also say "She didn't even know who was Pirandello", with no change in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Indirect or embedded questions follow the affirmative order. Thus, if we have:

- Who **is Pirandello**?

the question needs to be reported as:

- She didn't know who **Pirandello was**. (Imitating the order in: **Pirandello was** an Italian writer, where "Pirandello" is the subject and "an Italian writer" is the subject complement.)

A sentence containing "She didn't know who was ..." would only be possible if the phrase completing the blank were the subject complement, for example:

- Who was the author of "Six Characters in Search of an Author"?

In this particular case, the question could be reported as:

- She didn't know who **was the author of ...**. (Imitating the order in: Pirandello **was the author of ...**.)